# datagrid not scrolling image correctly

Tags: image, actionscript, datagrid

I have a datagrid that has a itemRenderer. that will display one or two images within a cell based on data values.

all works except when I scroll the grid. whats happening is the images are showing up in cell were they should not. I have checked to make sure the data is being passed to the itemRenderer is correct. I'm using flash builder 4.6.

itemRenderer:

```
<mx:DataGridColumn headerText="" dataField="isComment" visible="true">
                        <mx:itemRenderer>
                            <fx:Component>
                                <mx:HBox height="32" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalScrollPolicy="off" verticalScrollPolicy="off">

                                    <fx:Script>
                                        <![CDATA[
                                            override public function set data(value:Object):void
                                            {
                                                super.data = value;

                                                if(data.isComment){
                                                    CommentImage.load("images/comment.png");
                                                }else{
                                                    CommentImage.load("");
                                                }

                                                if(data.isException){
                                                    ExceptionImage.load("images/exception.png");
                                                }else{
                                                    ExceptionImage.load("");
                                                }

                                            }
                                        ]]>
                                    </fx:Script>

                                        <mx:Image id="CommentImage" />
                                        <mx:Image id="ExceptionImage"/>


                                </mx:HBox>
                            </fx:Component>
                        </mx:itemRenderer>
                    </mx:DataGridColumn>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the other cell can't be empty. So I have created a image that is blank (white background) this seems to work for now, not sure if it the correct way or not.